# How do I initiate each different type of input and select elements since I submit it?

Tags: javascript, select, input

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijepi.jpg)

```
let typeValue =  [];
let namedValue =  [];
let dateValue = [];
let amountValue =  [];
let optionsValue =  [];

submit.addEventListener('click',expense)

function expense(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    

    let tr = document.createElement('tr');    
    expenseTable.append(tr);

    let td = document.createElement('td');   
    tr.append(td);
    td.innerHTML = `${typeValue}`;

    createElement(namedValue);
    createElement(dateValue);
    createElement(amountValue);
    createElement(optionsValue);

    function createElement(a) {
        td = document.createElement('td');     
        tr.append(td);
        td.innerHTML = a;    
    } 
        
    //❓question

}
```

hello. I'm making Expense Tracker. and working on putting the data on the below line when I click submit.

How do I make input and select elements empty since I submit them???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reset the form by writing this:

```
e.target.reset();
```

For more information about this, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: Thank you to let me know 'reset()'.   Can I ask you more?

so I made code like this. and  It's not working inside of 'function expense'. 

what can I do?? 

`submit.addEventListener('click',expense)

function expense(e) {
~~~~~

     initiate;  
}

function initiate() {
    typeValue.reset;
    namedValue.reset;
    dateValue.reset;
    amountValue.reset;
    optionsValue.reset;
} `

Comment: That's because you don't want to react to the `click` event of a `button` but to the `submit` event of the `form`. Once you do that just call the line of code in my answer to reset the whole form.